# How to upgrade NSCoding's initWithCoder as properties in a class are changing?

Tags: nscoding, nsarchiving

My class has some added properties and I change my class's initWithCoder to parse out the new types.
This causes a crash if the archive file is still using the old format.  How do I sensibly implement the code without causing such a crash as properties changes in a class over time?